# Flutter: Edit an existing item using provider

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app that works like so.

User creates a report `EquipmentReport` and on that report, they can add a list of `AdditionalWN` via a form called `NotificationForm`

The user should be able to add / delete and change any of the `AdditionalWN` items on the report

As the `AdditionalWN` is quite a complex model, I have implemented a ChangeNotifier on both the `EquipmentReport` and the `AdditionalWN`

EquipmentReport

```
class EquipmentReport extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<AdditionalWN> _notifications;
  List<ReportImage> _imgs;
  List<bool> _inspectionResultSelectedStates;

  String _locationIDVerification;
  String _inspectionComments;

  UnmodifiableListView<AdditionalWN> get notifications => UnmodifiableListView(_notifications);
  void addNotification(AdditionalWN notification) {
    _notifications.add(notification);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void removeRemoveNotification(AdditionalWN notification) {
    _notifications.remove(notification);
    notifyListeners();
  }
.........
```

AdditionalWN

```
class AdditionalWN extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _id = UniqueKey().toString();
  String _notificationText = '';
  String _notificationTitle = '';
  int _isFault = 1;
  int _isBreakdown = 0;
  int _isWorkComplete = 0;
  int _probabilityOfFailure = 0;
  int _consequencePeople = 0;
  int _consequenceEnvironment = 0;
  int _consequenceReputation = 0;
  int _consequenceAsset = 0;
  int _equipmentID = 0;


  String get id => _id;

  int get equipmentID => _equipmentID;
  set equipmentID(int value) {
    _equipmentID = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get notificationText => _notificationText;
  set notificationText(String value) {
    _notificationText = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  String get notificationTitle => _notificationTitle;
  set notificationTitle(String value) {
    _notificationTitle = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
..........
```

Adding a new `AdditionalWN` to the report is working fine using this button on the `EquipmentReport` where I pass a new instance of the `ChangeNotifierProvider<AdditionalWN>` to my `NotificationForm()`

```
ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Add'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        //here we create a new instance of the AdditionalWM and change provider to send to the new page
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<AdditionalWN>(
                            create: (context) => AdditionalWN(),
                            builder: (context, child) => NotificationForm(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
```

Where I am struggling is how do I let me user edit an existing `AdditionalWN`?

Currently when a user clicks the edit button on the list of `AdditionalWN`s they get an error.

```
A AdditionalWN was used after being disposed.

Once you have called dispose() on a AdditionalWN, it can no longer be used.
The relevant error-causing widget was
NotificationForm
```

Here is my code to allow them to navigate to the `NotificationForm`

```
ListTile(
                        leading: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              //here we need to pass an existing model and change provider using  ChangeNotifierProvider.value so we can edit
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
                                  value: model.notifications[index],
                                  child: NotificationForm(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                        ),
```

I'm really lost on how to be able to pass both a new `AdditionalWN` to the `NotificationForm` as well as an exsiting `AdditionalWN` to the same `NotificationForm`

Comment: Why do you have `AdditionalWN` be a `ChangeNotifier`? It sounds like you are over engineering things. Consider keeping `EquipmentReport`  as `ChangeNotifier` and instead of editing individual `AdditionalWN` simply create new ones, and replace existing ones. I don't know if this will work for you depending on your design. Maybe you need finer control over what's being rebuilt, but the approach I mentioned will simply things, and generally that's an aim you should seek even at the expense of some performance.

Comment: @moneeralhashim it does indeed seem a little cover engineered. The reason `AdditionalWN` is a change notifier is that on the `NotificationForm` I have lots of widgets that change based on the values in `AdditionalWN` so thought implementing the provider pattern there would also be good practice?

Comment: Can you add the answer, if you have managed to solve this.